# Changing the "Invalid Password" message in User Manager

Tags: user-management, user-profile

We changed the password complexity for users using a

> passwordStrengthRegularExpression

property, it works fine but how can we inform the user about the format of password needed. 
For example if the user need to change his password and he didn't know the regex he can't spend a lot of time without founding the best password format.

By default sitecore display this message

[image]

and if we create a new user also the error message didn't give any information's about the needed password format

[image]

How can we customize these error messages?

We are using sitecore 8.2 with SXA1.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message is a dictionary entry in the `core` database in Sitecore.

Go to Sitecore Desktop, switch to `core` database and find the item:

Path: `/sitecore/system/Dictionary/F/Failed to set the password   Possible reasons are   1  The old password is incorrect  2  The new p_1`

ID: `{098CF1DA-CF18-412A-9EE9-A82E14BA3731}`

Enter any `Phrase` value you want:

[image: Sitecore Failed to set the password dictionary entry]

I did test it and it worked:

[image]

Be aware that:

- There are 2 items with similar names. Make sure you edit the correct one.
- You should not change the key - only set the `Phrase` field value.

Comment: HI @Marek thank you for your return. I checked this item but changing the Phrase value didn't changed the message displayed. I found the message displayed for adding a new user and by changing this item "/sitecore/system/Dictionary/T/The password is invalid" I saw my changes. Did you have any idea about this issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tested it and it works on my laptop (see screenshots above). There are 2 items with similar names - make sure you edit the correct one and that you only edit the `Phrase` field, not `Key`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Marek thank you it works fine, I don't know why the first time I didn't seen my changes. Just notice that for me it's not the same GUID **{5BB66CB4-F2BC-E08E-9563-28194D5C9779}**

For adding a new user with User Manger if you want to change the password error message located here

"/sitecore/system/Dictionary/T/The password is invalid"

[image]