# Restrict all users from login to Sitecore except admin

Tags: sitecore-client, login

I want to provide an option to admin so that they can allow or restrict all users (except admin) from logging in to Sitecore. Custom error message should be displayed on Sitecore login screen if access is restricted.

Active Directory authentication is enabled. How to change the default error message to display the entered custom error message if users are restricted ?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 171121)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it as follows :

1. Switch to the core database
2. Navigate to `/sitecore/system/Dictionary/{first character of the message}/{actual message}`
3. Select the {actual message} item. Then, change the field name called "phrase" as per your wish.

All the messages displayed in Sitecore seems to be here

**Reference :** https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/12584/4515

Comment: Ok. this is the place to add custom message. I need to interject login request before it authenticates user (before active directory authentication starts) and if that user is restricted , then show custom message. which processor should be extended to add this business login and add custom message ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of it. Hope your original question on how to set the custom error message was answered. Please mark this as the answer if you find it so.. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the custom error message using processor was the question. Thanks for answering where can we update the existing error message.

Comment: Welcome. Do upvote the answer